# Creating a dataframe with condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have built a dataframe representing strings of flight and the flights that are in that string.

This is the code (**only for information purpose**) for obtaining the actual dataframe:

```
string = 0;
d = []
for i in data_file.index:
    for j in data_file.index:
        list_strings = find_all_paths(graph,i,j)
        for k in range(len(list_strings)):
            string = string + 1;
            for m in range(len(list_strings[k])):
                d.append({'path':list_strings[k][m],'string': string})
```

**The problem I want to solve:** the outcome of this code is the following (a sample, since it is pretty big):

```
path  string
-------------
0       1
1       1
2       1
0       2
2       3
4       3
...    ...
```

The outcome means: string 1 is: first flight 1 is operated, followed by flight 1 and finally flight 2. String 2 is flight 0 and then flight 2.

I would like to get a dataframe that contains the extremes of a string, this is the first and last flight of the string.

Expected result:

```
string  first   last
---------------------
1        0       2
2        0       0
3        2       4
...     ...     ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.concat()` with `groupby()`:

```
pd.concat([df.groupby('string').first(), df.groupby('string').last()], axis=1)
```

Yields:

```
        path  path
string            
1          0     2
2          0     0
3          2     4
```

Comment: How can I name the columns 'path', 'path' by 'first' and 'last'?

Comment: The most efficient method for doing so would be @anky_91's answer below! Using `agg(['first','last'])` specifies that you are aggregating two new columns called `first` and `last`, that also use the `first()` and `last()` aggregation functions, performed on the `path` column.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
print(df.groupby('string')['path'].agg(['first','last']))
```

---

```
        first last
string           
1.0        0    2
2.0        0    0
3.0        2    4
```